# Call to String.Concat causing high-cpu not showing in CPU Usage tab

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, cpu-usage

My sample app looks as follows.

```
class Program
    {
        static List<XmlNode> memList = new List<XmlNode>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start");
            Console.ReadKey();
            CauseHighCPU();
        }



        static public void CauseHighCPU()
        {
            string str = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                str += " Hello World";
            }
        }
}
```

I expect string concatenation to cause high cpu. When I profile the application using PerfView, this is very loud and clear.

[image]

I am trying to do similar analysis using Visual Studio 2017 Diagnostics Hub. Below is what its CPU usage tab shows.

[image]

Its Call-tree view not showing any call to Concat, although, there are some External Code here
[image]

This makes me think that it may related to something missing in my configration. As you can see here, Enable Just My Code is unchecked.

[image]

Also not sure if its related but here is symbols settings.

[image]

Any thouhts what could be wrong that is causing VS not showing root cause of high-cpu usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not look in the options of *Debugging* but in the options of *Performance Tools* and then disable "Just my code":

[image: Options: disable "Just my code" in Performance tools]

Comment: this was it my friend. Thanks a lot. However, this is now bringing up too much "junk" from ntdll.dll, wow64.dll. PerfView view is just too cleaner. Is there anyway to get same type of stack here in VS?

Comment: @jimcrown: sorry, I don't know of a way cleaning that up in Visual Studio

Comment: no worries, I will post a separate question here because this is a separate topic anyways